# QuantLib Python Hull-White Callable Bond with Normal Volatility

Tags: python, evaluation, quantlib

I am evaluating several callable bonds using QuantLib Python Cookbook's approach below with Hull-White model

1. Is the **sigma** below in **ql.HullWhite** normal or log-normal
   volatility?
2. If it is log-normal, are there any ways to feed normal volatility instead to **ql.HullWhite**?

Thank you very much,

```
bond = ql.CallableFixedRateBond(
    settlement_days, face_amount,
    schedule, [coupon], accrual_daycount,
    ql.Following, face_amount, issue_date,
    callability_schedule)

def value_bond(a, sigma, grid_points, bond):
    model = ql.HullWhite(ts_handle, a, sigma)
    engine = ql.TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine(model, grid_points)
    bond.setPricingEngine(engine)

value_bond(0.03, 0.12, 40, bond)
print("Bond price: %lf" % bond.cleanPrice())

Bond price: 68.396593
```